# Windows 8 locks after ~13 minutes

Tags: windows-8, lock-screen

I am using Windows 8.1 at work, and for the past week or two, my computer keeps getting locked after about 13-16 minutes from the last time.

It doesn't matter that I am constantly working on it. It can happen while I type something on the keyboard, or while I use the mouse to browse the internet. The screen just suddenly goes dark, and when I move the mouse again, I get into the lock screen, and I have to put in my password to keep using my computer.

I discovered that when I restart the computer, the trouble seems to go away, but the next day it returns. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that the display is being turned off over night, while the computer is running.

I tried changing the "Put the computer to sleep" setting in the Power Options, and switched it to "never", but that didn't solve my problem. I also tried disabling Remote Access, thinking that maybe some remote computer was trying to access my computer on a regular basis, which kicks me out locally.

I am also using the Chrome Remote Desktop app, so maybe this could cause some problems?

I looked through my eventlog, and saw nothing out of the ordinary.

I used to have the same problem before, on Windows 8, so I don't think it's related to the 8.1 specifically. I don't know how I fixed it in the past, it just seemed to resolve itself after a while.

Comment: A colleague with a bad sense of humour and a copy of PsTools? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx

Comment: I would ask your IT support staff for assistance.  There are so many variables this actually could be.

Comment: I showed it to my IT guy. He offered the Remote Desktop thing, and also had a look at the eventlog. He didn't have any other ideas.
After a restart it appeared to have been solved, but after a day it just returned. Maybe I should nag him some more to try and look into it.

Comment: @NoamGal In case you didn't already, you could try [performing a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us) to check whether the issue reappears.

Comment: Does you keyboard or device have a "lock" button? If so, it may be gummed up.